# How to clean cache after leaving a webpage ? php or any script?

Tags: php, html, browser-cache, cache-control

The issue is, every browser used to store cache of webpages, and whenever I update my webpage from the server, I can not see the updating until I perform refreshing of that page or clear the cache. 
So, this is a big problem for users/guests, for example, the visitor visits my webpage today, and I update my webpage that has important news, Whenever he will visit again, he will be unable to see the updating due to already stored cache on his/her system. Until he/she refresh the page or clear cache of the browser, the updating will be hidden.

Is there any solution of this issue ? because mostly no body used to refresh the page or good at clearing the cache. So, any idea how to solve it?

or If I am not wrong, can I do that when the visitor leaves my webpage, the cache of only my webpage deleted/cleared. Any php code, script or anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't control the cache on client browsers, but you can SUGGEST to them that they shouldn't cache your pages at all. you cannot reliably detect when a person leaves your pages.

Comment: Do you have access to server config? can you post a URL to the page, that will help to verify what is going on.

Comment: No, it is not a problem for me, but Whenever I update my webpage from the server side, and until I refresh the page, I can't see my updating. So, I was thinking that, the same problem will be with my visitors, perhaps. http://real3d.pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP :

```
if( !headers_sent() )
    {   header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . 'GMT');
        header('Cache-control: no-cache');
    }
```

Using HTML :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 04 Dec 1993 21:29:02 GMT">
```

**You can't clean clients cache but you can make it expire at specific time.**

Comment: wow.. It works.. Thanks. @Yousuf. 
Could you please tell me a little bit more, is there any disadvantages of doing this ? or anything that I should know ? My pages or not having so much bytes, so, what do you suggest ?  :)

Comment: This won't hurt but better approach is to be dynamic and use PHP in your websites. Then you don't need to use this.